# Access for global variables JavaScript unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Hello I am new JavaScript unit testing and I'm using Mocha.js and Chai.js

What I want to do is simply figure out how to check the value of a global variable in a seperate js file. Here is my code

Here is the main.js file (code to be tested) Just has the variable I want to test against.

```
//main.js
var foo = 9;
```

Here is my test file

```
var assert = require("assert")
var expect = require('chai').expect
var fs = require("fs")
var vm = require("vm")

function include(path){
    var code = fs.readFileSync(path,'utf-8');
    vm.runInThisContext(code,path);
}

describe('Global', function(){
    include('lib/main.js');
    it('Should check if value is matching', function(){
        expect(foo).to.equal(9);
    });
});
```

Again, I'm new to unit testing in JavaScript. Any help will be greatly appreciated. The error I get back is `foo is not defined` which tells me that it can't access the variable, so how can I access it? Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var foo = 9;` does not declare a global variable, it declares a local variable. In Node.js, a local variable declared in the outermost scope of a module will be local to that module.

If you want to test the value of a local variable declared in another file, your best bet is probably to read the contents of that file into a string (using `fs.readFileSync`, perhaps) and then `eval()` the string, which should define the variable in the current scope.

That will only work if the local variable is declared in the file's outermost scope. If it's a local variable inside a function, for example, you're out of luck (unless you want to do some gnarly string parsing, which would stretch the bounds of sanity).

Answer (score 2):

Your global object is usually `window`

a global `var foo = "test";` is the same as `window.foo = "test";` or `window['foo'] = "test";`

Window is not defined when mocha is run in node, but this [blog post](http://freepender.blogspot.de/2013/10/javascript-unit-testing-with-mocha.html) uses "this" combined with a self-invoking function to get the same result.

Comment: Yeah `window` doesn't run in node. Sorry for not clarifying.  Using `this` just returns `undefined` for the argument.

Comment: ok, you're right it's not as clear as it should have been. I'll edit it accordingly. Thanks, @Louis!

Comment: In Node.js the global object is `global`.